# What does the Ruby `uniq` method use for equality checking?

Tags: ruby

I'm interested in implementing a custom equality method for use in an array of objects in Ruby. Here's a stripped-back example:

```
class Foo

  attr_accessor :a, :b

  def initialize(a, b)
    @a = a
    @b = b
  end 

  def ==(other)
    puts 'doing comparison'
    @a == @a && @b == @b
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@a}: #{@b}"  
  end

end 

a = [
  Foo.new(1, 1),
  Foo.new(1, 2),
  Foo.new(2, 1),
  Foo.new(2, 2),
  Foo.new(2, 2)
]
a.uniq
```

I expected the uniq method to call `Foo#==`, and remove the last instance of Foo. Instead, I don't see the 'doing comparison' debug line and the array remains the same length.

Notes:

- I'm using ruby 2.2.2
- I've tried defining the method as `===`
- I have done it long-hand with `a.uniq{|x| [x.a, x.b]}`, but I don't like this solution it's making the code look pretty cluttered.

Comment: Are we to assume that neither answer was helpful?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It compares values using their hash and eql? methods for efficiency.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq-3F

So you should override `eql?` ([that is `==`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F)) and `hash`

UPDATE:

I cannot explain fully why is that, but overriding `hash` and `==` doesn't work. I guess it's cause by the way `uniq` is implemented in C:

From: array.c (C Method):
Owner: Array
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 20

```
static VALUE
rb_ary_uniq(VALUE ary)
{
    VALUE hash, uniq;

    if (RARRAY_LEN(ary) <= 1)
        return rb_ary_dup(ary);
    if (rb_block_given_p()) {
        hash = ary_make_hash_by(ary);
        uniq = rb_hash_values(hash);
    }
    else {
        hash = ary_make_hash(ary);
        uniq = rb_hash_values(hash);
    }
    RBASIC_SET_CLASS(uniq, rb_obj_class(ary));
    ary_recycle_hash(hash);

    return uniq;
}
```

You can bypass that by using a block version of uniq:

```
> [Foo.new(1,2), Foo.new(1,2), Foo.new(2,3)].uniq{|f| [f.a, f.b]}
=> [#<Foo:0x0000562e48937cc8 @a=1, @b=2>, #<Foo:0x0000562e48937c78 @a=2, @b=3>]
```

Or use `Struct` instead:

```
F = Struct.new(:a, :b)
[F.new(1,2), F.new(1,2), F.new(2,3)].uniq
# => [#<struct F a=1, b=2>, #<struct F a=2, b=3>]
```

UPDATE2:

Actually in terms of overriding it's not the same if you override `==` or `eql?`. When I overriden `eql?` It worked as intended:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :a, :b

  def initialize(a, b)
    @a = a
    @b = b
  end 

  def eql?(other)
    (@a == other.a && @b == other.b)
  end

  def hash
    [a, b].hash
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@a}: #{@b}"  
  end

end 

a = [
  Foo.new(1, 1),
  Foo.new(1, 2),
  Foo.new(2, 1),
  Foo.new(2, 2),
  Foo.new(2, 2)
]
a.uniq
#=> [#<Foo:0x0000562e483bff70 @a=1, @b=1>,
#<Foo:0x0000562e483bff48 @a=1, @b=2>,
#<Foo:0x0000562e483bff20 @a=2, @b=1>,
#<Foo:0x0000562e483bfef8 @a=2, @b=2>]
```

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: "I cannot explain fully why is that, but overriding `hash` and `==` doesn't work." – You wrote the answer yourself: "It compares values using their `hash` and `eql?` methods for efficiency."

Answer (score 6):

You can find the answer in [the documentation of `Array#uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-uniq) (for some reason, it is not mentioned in [the documentation of `Enumerable#uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-uniq)):

> It compares values using their `hash` and `eql?` methods for efficiency.

The contracts of `hash` and `eql?` are as follows:

- `hash` returns an `Integer` that *must* be the same for objects which are considered equal, but does not necessarily have to be different for objects that are not equal. This means that *different* hashes mean that the objects are definitely not equal, but the same hash doesn't tell you anything. Ideally, `hash` should also be resistant to accidental and deliberate collisions.
- `eql?` is value equality, usually stricter than `==` but less strict than `equal?` which is more or less identity: `equal?` should only return `true` if you compare an object to itself.

`uniq?` uses the same trick that is used in hash tables, hash sets, etc. to speed up lookups:

1. Compare the hashes. Computing a hash should normally be fast.
2. If the hashes are identical, then, and only then double-check using `eql?`.